# How to identify duplicate entries in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as follows.

```
     title  description 
0  mmm  mmm
1  mmm  mmm
2  mmm  mmm
3  mmm  mmm
4  mmm  mmm
5  mmm  mmm
6  mmm  mmm
7  nnn  nnn 
8  nnn  nnn
9  lll  lll
10  jjj  jjj
```

I want to keep one entry and remove all other duplicate entries while returning another dataframe that include details of the removed entries from the above dataframe.

For example, the output should be;

```
     title  description 
0  mmm  mmm 
1  nnn  nnn
2  lll  lll
3  jjj  jjj
```

and the details of the removed entries should outputted as;

```
     title  description count
0  mmm  mmm 6
1  nnn  nnn 1
```

My current code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"title":["mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "nnn", "nnn", "lll", "jjj"], "description":["mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "mmm", "nnn", "nnn", "lll", "jjj"]})
df.drop_duplicates()
```

However, it removes all the duplicates (which is not my intention).

Is it possible to do this in pandas in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method involved `duplicated`+`groupby.size`

First question

```
df[~df.duplicated()]
   title description
0    mmm         mmm
7    nnn         nnn
9    lll         lll
10   jjj         jjj
```

Second question

```
df[df.duplicated()].groupby(['title','description']).size()
title  description
mmm    mmm            6
nnn    nnn            1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi, just wondering how I can change the second code when I only have one single coloum with no heading as the pandas dataframe. Can I use the column number instead? :)

Comment: @EmJ you can check with value_counts